# JOptionPane "adding a window to a container" exception in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

When using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, I am getting an `IllegalArgumentException` when I try to specify the parent component. It works in Java but not in Clojure.
Despite what the exception says, I am not actually adding a window to a container. I am trying to create a separate frame and use it as a parent window for `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. Here is my Clojure code:

```
(def parent-frame
  (doto (new javax.swing.JFrame)
    (.setDefaultCloseOperation javax.swing.JFrame/DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
    (.pack)
    (.setVisible true)))
(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showMessageDialog parent-frame "Hello") ;pops up dialog
(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showInputDialog parent-frame "Hello?")  ;throws an exception
```

The equivalent Java code does what I expect:

```
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
parentFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
parentFrame.pack();
parentFrame.setVisible(true);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentFrame,"Hello"); //pops up a dialog
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parentFrame,"Hello?");  //pops up a dialog
```

Any idea why the Clojure code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is overloaded.

```
showInputDialog(Object message, Object initialSelectionValue)
...
showInputDialog(Component parentComp, Object message)
```

When you execute `(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showInputDialog parent-frame "Hello?")`, it seems that clojure invokes `showInputDialog(Object message, Object initialSelectionValue)`.

You can check this in your repl:

```
user=> (javax.swing.JOptionPane/showInputDialog parent-frame "hello")

IllegalArgumentException adding a window to a container  java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow (Container.java:490)
user=> *e
#error {
 :cause "adding a window to a container"
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   :message "adding a window to a container"
   :at [java.awt.Container checkNotAWindow "Container.java" 490]}]
 :trace
 [[java.awt.Container checkNotAWindow "Container.java" 490]
  [java.awt.Container addImpl "Container.java" 1091]
  [java.awt.Container add "Container.java" 973]
  [javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI addMessageComponents "BasicOptionPaneUI.java" 358]
  [com.apple.laf.AquaOptionPaneUI createMessageArea "AquaOptionPaneUI.java" 92]
  [javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI installComponents "BasicOptionPaneUI.java" 172]
  [javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI installUI "BasicOptionPaneUI.java" 141]
  [javax.swing.JComponent setUI "JComponent.java" 666]
  [javax.swing.JOptionPane setUI "JOptionPane.java" 1860]
  [javax.swing.JOptionPane updateUI "JOptionPane.java" 1882]
  [javax.swing.JOptionPane <init> "JOptionPane.java" 1845]
  [javax.swing.JOptionPane showInputDialog "JOptionPane.java" 568]
  [javax.swing.JOptionPane showInputDialog "JOptionPane.java" 494]
  [javax.swing.JOptionPane showInputDialog "JOptionPane.java" 455]
  [user$eval10619 invokeStatic "form-init4926112649336753943.clj" 1]
  [user$eval10619 invoke "form-init4926112649336753943.clj" 1]
  ...
```

If you check the `JOptionPane`'s source code and check the line 455,

```
public static String showInputDialog(Object message, Object initialSelectionValue) {
    return showInputDialog(null, message, initialSelectionValue); // <= Line 455
}
```

As you can see, `JOptionPane` allows to pass `Object` as a message. If you pass a `Component` as a message, it will be used as a message component.

In this case, `parent-frame` is passed as a message and later it tried to add this `parent-frame` (which is `Window`) to `Container`, which caused `IllegalArgumentException`.

I don't know how clojure decide which method to call when the target method is overloaded. Clojure picked wrong one. I think you should use other method to avoid this problem.

```
(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showInputDialog parent-frame "Hello?" "")
```

This will cause the clojure invoke `showInputDialog(Component parent, Object mess, String initialSelectionValue)`, and correctly show `JOptionPane`.

**EDIT**
You can also provide type hint for argument that clojure could pick correct method as @James mentioned in his answer. This would be the better way.

```
(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showInputDialog #^java.awt.Component parent-frame "Hello?")
```

Comment: Right. The difference between Clojure and Java is that Java distinguishes between overloaded methods by the number of parameters and their types, but Clojure only distinguishes by the number of parameters. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` is overloaded:

```
showInputDialog(Object message, Object initialSelectionValue)
showInputDialog(Component parentComp, Object message)
```

Java distinguishes between overloaded methods by the number of parameters and their types, but Clojure only distinguishes by the number of parameters. You can get Clojure to call the right method by type hinting:

```
(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showInputDialog #^java.awt.Component parent-frame "Hello?")
```

There is more information here: [How do I call overloaded Java methods in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722856/how-do-i-call-overloaded-java-methods-in-clojure)